# AdMobs Banner: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445239/android-admob-banner-add-on-top-of-canvas) to implement my AdMob Banners, however I am getting an error: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.

I have already added the following line to the `build.gradle` :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Here is my `onCreate()` method:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(testBanner);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //scale image
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    dispX = size.x;
    dispY = size.y;
    bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.bg),dispX,dispY,true);
    ls = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.losescreen),GamePanel.rescaleX(805),GamePanel.rescaleY(1105),true);
    Pb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.playbutton),GamePanel.rescaleX(242),GamePanel.rescaleY(242),true);

    View gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(gamePanel);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);


    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    setContentView(layout);
    contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();

}
```

Comment: Have you considered [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) when running your code? "To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either: (1) A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.(2) The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the SDK manager and download `Google Play Services` and, if you haven't already, `Google Play Repository`.

[image]

(http://jmsliu.com/2085/add-admob-with-google-play-service.html)

Thats it. That line in the gradle signifies nothing until you install this. To open the SDK manager:

[image]

(envyandroid.com)

Let me know if it worked after installing the `Google Play Services`. If it did, make sure to accept an answer. If you need more help, feel free to ask me any more questions!

Hope it helped! :-)

Comment: Well I assumed I had already done this because the Interstitial Ads worked before I added the banner ones.